# PHP connected to Azure MySQL but can't access table

Tags: php, mysql, azure

I have created a table in PHPmyAdmin called "people" with 4 columns and filled it with 2 rows of data. I used this piece of code from Azure's documentation in a file called "db.php" to connect to the database.

db.php:

```
$connectstr_dbhost = '';
$connectstr_dbname = '';
$connectstr_dbusername = '';
$connectstr_dbpassword = '';

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, "MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb") !== 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $connectstr_dbhost = preg_replace("/^.*Data Source=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbname = preg_replace("/^.*Database=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbusername = preg_replace("/^.*User Id=(.+?);.*$/", "\\1", $value);
    $connectstr_dbpassword = preg_replace("/^.*Password=(.+?)$/", "\\1", $value);
}

$link = mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
```

It successfully echoes `Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made!...`

Now, following a youtube tutorial, I'm trying to pass the data of my table and convert it to json format using this piece of code:

fetch.php:

```
include_once('db.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `people`";

$res = mysqli_query($link,$query);

if($res !== FALSE)
{
    echo "table found";
}
else
{
    echo "table not found";
}

$result = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) )
    array_push($result, array(  'id' => $row[0],
                                'firstname'  => $row[1],
                                'lastname' => $row[2],
                                'address' => $row[3]));

echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
```

But this just echoes `table not found`

I'm very new to both SQL and PHP. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you fill the credentials?

Comment: @PseudoAj what credentials? How do I find those and where do I enter them? Would they not be needed during connection as well though?

Comment: The `db.php` contains `$connectstr_dbhost = '';` there you need enter your host credentials.

Comment: @PseudoAj I thought that was the point of the `foreach`-statement. Because after I have echoed out `$connectstr_dbhost` at the end of the code it outputs "localdb" which is exactly the database I'm trying to access. Do you mean that this variable should hold more than one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mixing MySQL and MySQLi. The last code block (which converts the table into JSON) is using MySQL. I changed this and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your codes, it looks like you are using the Azure MySQL In App. By default, Azure injects the database connection information through  `MYSQLCONNSTR_localdb` variable at run-time environment. And the database name it injects into the variable is named: `localdb`.

So I am wondering under which database have you created the `people` table? If you have put the `people` table into other database, like the screenshot below:
[image]

Then the code in your `fetch.php` file will echo `table not found`; if you have put the table inside the `localdb` database, then it will  echo `table found”;

You can add the phpMyAdmin extension through Azure Portal, like below screenshot:

[image]

Then you can view your database content through the url: `https://{YOUR WEB APP’S NAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin/` to enter the workbench.

Besides, you can refer to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/08/18/announcing-mysql-in-app-preview-for-web-apps/) for more details regarding how MySQL in-app works for Web Apps.

Comment: Yes the table is in localdb which I am sure the php file is connected to: [image](http://i.imgur.com/YiOXIxA.png). I am not sure what adding the extension adds to the functionality as I was already able to access `https://{YOUR WEB APP’S NAME}.scm.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin/` right after I enabled "Azure MySQL In App" and restarted the app.